# How to create a snowball in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I am trying to create a 3d snowball with a splash effect for my game. What and how should I do? I also checked google for any the asset that I can use but could not find anything :/ Any asset or tutorial would be perfect!

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can create a normal ball and add a snow material on it to make it look like a snowball! I found some assets that might be useful. Don't just type "snow ball" in the unity asset store, type just "snow" and then look for something useful!

Some useful asset links:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/2d/textures-materials/texture-snow-11988
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/2d/textures-materials/realistic-snow-and-ice-materials-151129
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/audio/sound-fx/footstep-snow-and-grass-90678
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/one-click-snow-103458

Comment: thanks a lot for you reply, I checked the store again and found something usefull for me!